# Iterating over segmented 2D array in Python

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I have a 2D array which show a clustered map of countries and every counry is segmented with a specific value. How can I iterate over the value of every cluster?

Comment: Can you share a representative sample of your input?

Comment: 1D example:
[5, 5, 5, 5, 2 , 2, 2, 2] 
and I want to iterate 5 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
New_list= list(set(your_array))
for cluster in New_list:
       print(cluster)
       #this gives you 5 and 2
```

Comment: I want to iterate over every value only once. That means if a cluster/country is shown through many segments of value 5, I want to iterate 5 once.

Comment: Please show a sample to better understand where to break from the loop

Comment: 1D example:
[5, 5, 5, 5, 2 , 2, 2, 2] 
and I want to iterate 5 and 2

Comment: You can use a set to eliminate repated elements, try list(set(your_array)) and you'll have it without repated elements, then use a for loop once

Comment: Hamid, anything?

Comment: Thank's it works. I only had one problem because I had an array of arrays and set() generated error so I had to reshape the array.